# How can i calculate age, in angular2 hen I run it, it gets undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

how can I calculate age from a date? This is my code. When I run it, it gets undefined in the field that I want to appear.

this is component 1

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  DatosDTO
} from '../../dto/datos'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datos-personales',
  templateUrl: './datos-personales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datos-personales.component.css']
})
export class DatosPersonalesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  datosDTO: DatosDTO;

  public age: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.datosDTO = new DatosDTO();
  }
  CalculateAge(): void {
    if (this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento) {
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento);
      this.age = Math.ceil((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
    }
  }
}
```

this is class

```js
export class DatosPersona {
  tipoIdentificacion: string = "";
  numeroIdentificacion: string = "";
  nombres: string = "";
  apellidos: string = "";
  fechaNacimiento: number;
}
```

this is html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <label>Edad</label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 columns">
    <input readonly type="text" [value]="CalculateAge()">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing return type for the method

```
CalculateAge(){
    if (this.datosDTO  && this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento) {
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento);
      this.age = Math.ceil((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
      return this.age;
    } else {
      return '';
    }

  }
```

Also your object `fechaNacimiento`is not considered as date object. So use below

```
var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - 
     Date.parse(this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento));
```

Note that the `datosDTO` object is undefined initially. So add a check to it will fix your problem

Comment: Hello, in the field appears NaN

Comment: @EDWARDFABIANTAPIEROGOMEZ upvote too. :) by earning 15 reputation